# TypedQuery instead of normal Query in JPA

Tags: jakarta-ee, jpa, glassfish-3, jpql

Is it possible to write this Query as a TypedQuery and let the two Long's run into a Object with two public Long fields inside.

```
    Query q = em.createQuery(
            "SELECT c.id, COUNT(t.id) " +
            "FROM PubText t " +
            "JOIN t.comm c " +
            "WHERE c.element = ?1 " +
            "GROUP BY c.id");
    q.setParameter(1, e);
    List<?> rl = q.getResultList();
    Iterator<?> it = rl.iterator();
    HashMap<Long, Long> res = new HashMap<Long, Long>();
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        Object[] n = (Object[]) it.next();
        res.put((Long)n[0], (Long)n[1]);
    }
    return res;
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

JPA has a feature just for this - constructor expressions:

```
Query q = entityManager.createQuery("SELECT NEW com.example.DTO( c.id, COUNT(t.id)) FROM ...");
List<DTO> dtos = q.getResultList();
```

Your DTO class can be a POJO. All it will need is a public constructor accepting 2 `Long`s. Please note that you have to provide a fully qualified name of your class after the `NEW`operator.

Comment: hi @kostja I am getting an error (Cannot create TypedQuery for query with more than one return). My SQL looks like this: `SELECT NEW com.company.ui.EntityIDKey(c.companyId, c.name) FROM Company c WHERE c.companyId is not null and c.name is not null and length(trim(c.name)) > 0 order by c.name asc`. I am using a TypedQuery as follows: `List<EntityIDKey> companies = getEntityManager().createQuery(sql, EntityIDKey.class).getResultList();`

Comment: this can be the case if your EntityIDKey is not an entity. The provider is free to not support such queries. Have you tried using a regular Query?

Comment: that is true, `EntityIDKey` is not an entity. I am using Hibernate provider and somehow presumed it will work. A regular query that builds a collection of `Company` works just fine.

Comment: Sort of. I would be happier if the type safety warning can be avoided because `q.getResultList()` returns a generic type List.

Comment: Ah yes, unfortunately, the only way that I am aware of to get rid of those is to tell Java that you actually know what you are doing by using `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")`. Perhaps there is a more typesafe way with the Criteria API, but I am not familiar enough with it.

Comment: If I annotate `EntityIDKey` with @Entity (even though it is not persisted; it is just a DTO between service layer and UI controller), is that going against a pattern or convention? That way, I can use a `TypedQuery`.

Comment: As long as you do not generate tables from your entities (check your persistence.xml when in doubt), you should be fine with 'fake' entities. However, IMHO suppressing type warnings is a direct (and thus comprehensible) way of dealing with the issue, while simulating entities is more of a workaround. If I as a later maintainer would see an entity without a corresponding table, it would take me some time to figure out the purpose.

Comment: @kostja: _Since the DTO is probably not an entity, you cannot use TypedQuery._ This is not correct. From http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#createQuery%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Class%29 it is allowed, hence the constructor expression in the JSR-317 clearly states that: "A constructor may be used in the SELECT list to return an instance of a Java class. The specified class is not required to be an entity or to be mapped to the database. The constructor name must be fully qualified."

Comment: Yeah, I wonder why I was so certain of this restriction :) Thank you for the catch, @cinhtau , sentence removed.

Answer (score 13):

New code looks like this now. 
Thanks for you help.

```
    TypedQuery<CommUsed> q = em.createQuery(
        "SELECT new CommUsed(c.id,COUNT(t.id)) " +
        "FROM PubText t " +
        "JOIN t.comm c " +
        "WHERE c.element = ?1 " +
        "GROUP BY c.id", CommUsed.class);
    q.setParameter(1, e);
    HashMap<Long, Long> res = new HashMap<Long, Long>();
    for (CommUsed u : q.getResultList())
        res.put(u.commID, u.cnt);
```

Comment: I see, so you can use TypedQueries after all :) good to know. Unfortunately there seems to be no reasonable way to fill a `Map` right from the query, so the transformation part in the last 3 lines has to stay, I'm afraid.

Comment: Ach, that fine. We don't need to press everything into one line like in the old C days. :-)

Comment: @HasanTuncay why did you not leverage the constructor expression feature suggested by @kostja?

Comment: I did. I just added the TypedQuery type checking to it.