# Is there any spring jpa equivalent to following query

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

Query :

```
@Query("Select p.name,t.points from Player p,Tournament t where t.id=?1 And p.id=t.player_id")
```

I have my player and tournament entity and their corresponding JPA repositories. But the problem is we can get only entities from our query, but i want to do above query, please help me with this i am new to it.

this is my sql query i want to add but where to add i am not getting:

```
Select p.name, t.points_rewarded from player p, participant t where t.tournament_id="1" and t.player_id=p.id;
```

Comment: So does `List<Integer> findDayPlayedByGameIdAndDayPlayedGreaterThan(Long gameId,Integer gameDayCycle);` work?

Comment: No, i want list of DayPlayed column which is integer from dailybonus table, but the above return list of dailybonus object

Comment: If I am not wrong, above query is also a JPQL query.

Comment: No you would have to use a `@Query` for that, the `findBy` will only work for  entities.

Comment: @M.Deinum see example 1.4 from this link, i was writing similar query methods, http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.4.3.RELEASE/reference/html/repositories.html#repositories.query-methods , yes but in that example in result they are getting people list and people class must be an entity.

Comment: As stated it will only work for entities of collections, pages,... that contain entities. For custom return values you will have to use a `@Query`.

Comment: thanks @M.Deinum that removed my confusion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This is how you can do it with JPQL for JPA:**

```
String queryString = "select p.name, t.points from Tournament t," +
            " Player p where t.player_id=p.id " +
            "and t.id= :id_tournament";

Query query = this.entityManager.createQuery(queryString);
query.setParameter("id_tournament", 1);
List results = query.getResultList();
```

You can take a look at this [**JPA Query Structure (JPQL / Criteria)**](http://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/query/jpql/structure) for further information about JPQL queries.

---

**And this is ho you can do it using HQL for Hibernate**, these are two ways of doing it:

```
String hql = "SELECT p.name, t.points from Player p,Tournament t WHERE t.id= '1' And p.id=t.player_id";
Query query = session.createQuery(hql);
List results = query.list();
```

Or using **`query.setParameter()`** method like this:

```
String hql = "SELECT p.name, t.points from Player p,Tournament t WHERE t.id= :tournament_id And p.id=t.player_id";
Query query = session.createQuery(hql);
query.setParameter("tournament_id",1);
List results = query.list();
```

You can take a look at this [**HQL Tutorial**](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/hibernate/hibernate_query_language.htm) for further information about HQL queries.

---

**Note:**

In both cases you will get a list of Object's array `List<Object[]>` where element one `array[0]` is the `p.name` and the second one is `t.points`.

Comment: which, of course, is not JPA/JPQL that the question asks for, and you could adapt what you wrote there to actually use JPA

Comment: @NeilStockton I thought the OP was looking for a solution with one of the Two technologies, I updated my answer to include both a `JPA` and a `Hibernate` solutions.

Comment: thanks a lot using entity manager, its done, thanks i was stuck in it 4-5 hrs, you saved me, i also need to add @transactional in the method, then its working fine.

Answer (score 0):

[TypedQuery instead of normal Query in JPA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15413434/typedquery-instead-of-normal-query-in-jpa)
this is what i was looking for, thanks chsdk for help, i have to create pojos class, and in above link answer is working fine foe me,
Here is my code sample

```html
String querystring = "SELECT new example.restDTO.ResultDTO(p.name,t.pointsRewarded) FROM Player p, Participant t where t.tournamentId=?1 AND t.playerId = p.id ORDER by t.pointsRewarded DESC";
EntityManager em = this.emf.createEntityManager();
try {
 Query queryresults =  em.createQuery(querystring).setParameter(1, tournamentId);
 List<ResultDTO> result =queryresults.getResultList();
 return new ResponseEntity<>(result, HttpStatus.OK);
} catch (Exception e) {
 e.printStackTrace();
 return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
} finally {
if (em != null) {
 em.close();
 }}
```